# Argument Passing and Stack Setup in C

Tags: c, stack, parameter-passing, page-fault

I am currently trying to implement argument passing for part of a project in my operating systems course. We need to parse and tokenize a file name, and store (using memcpy) the values of the arguments, pointers to the arguments, and a few other miscellaneous formatting features.

It must follow the format exemplified by this diagram (where the example command is /bin/ls -l foo bar):[image]

Here is the my solution. Currently, it is causing page faults which suggests that the argument passing is not working as intended.

```
static bool
setup_stack (void **esp, const char* file_name)
{
  uint8_t *kpage;
  bool success = false;

  kpage = palloc_get_page (PAL_USER | PAL_ZERO);
  if (kpage != NULL)
    {
      success = install_page (((uint8_t *) PHYS_BASE) - PGSIZE, kpage, true);
      if (success)
        *esp = PHYS_BASE;
      else
        palloc_free_page (kpage);
        return success;
    }

  /* Our code starts here */

  int i = 0;
  int argc = get_argc(file_name);
  char *token, *save_ptr;
  char **argv = malloc((argc + 1) * sizeof(char *));
  size_t token_size;

  //generate argv and push args onto stack
  for (token = strtok_r((char *)file_name, " ", &save_ptr); token != NULL; token = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &save_ptr)) {
    token_size = strlen(token) + 1;
    *esp = *esp - token_size;
    argv[i] = *esp;
    i++;
    memcpy(*esp, token, token_size);
  } argv[argc] = 0;

 //perform alignment
  size_t alignment = (size_t) *esp % 4;
  if (alignment) {
    *esp = *esp - alignment;
    memcpy(*esp, &argv[argc], alignment);
  }

  //push argv pointers
  for (i = argc; i >= 0; i--) {
    *esp = *esp - sizeof(char *);
    memcpy(*esp, &argv[i], sizeof(char *));
  }

  //push pointer to argv
  ptr = *esp;
  *esp = *esp - sizeof(char *);
  memcpy(*esp, &ptr, sizeof(char *));

  //push argc
  *esp = *esp - sizeof(int);
  memcpy(*esp, &argc, sizeof(int));

  //push dummy return address
  *esp = *esp - sizeof(void *);
  memcpy(*esp, &argv[argc], sizeof(void *));

  free(argv);

  return success;
}
```

And the helper function I wrote called get_argc():

```
/* Return the number of tokens given a command 'file_name.' */
int get_argc(const char* file_name) {
    int argc = 0;
    char *buffer, *token, *save_ptr;
    buffer = malloc(sizeof(file_name));
    strlcpy(buffer, file_name, sizeof(file_name));
    for (token = strtok_r((char *)buffer, " ", &save_ptr); token != NULL; token = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &save_ptr)) {
        argc++;
    }
    free(buffer);
    return argc;
}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who takes a look at this.
EDIT: code formatting

Comment: I should note that the project spec says the order of the args themselves on the stack does not matter, only the order of the pointers to them. This is why the ordering of our arg placement may not agree with the diagram.

Comment: `sizeof file_name` is wrong: That only gives you the size of a pointer (likely 4 or 8 bytes).

Comment: good catch @melpomene. I changed it to strlen(file_name) + 1. Still getting  page faults however

Comment: do you really mean 'page fault' of 'segmentation fault'?

Comment: yeah, this code is running on a very primitive os that we are working with. e.g.                                                                                                             `+ args-many a b c: dying due to interrupt 0x0e (#PF Page-Fault Exception).
+ Interrupt 0x0e (#PF Page-Fault Exception) at eip=0x804870c
+  cr2=c0000008 error=00000005
+  eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000
+  esi=00000000 edi=00000000 esp=bfffffe4 ebp=00000000
+  cs=001b ds=0023 es=0023 ss=0023
`

Comment: amongst many other problems, like the posted code is missing the #include statements for the needed header files,  When calling `malloc()`, the code should always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: Please consistently indent the code, for readability and understandability

Comment: regarding this line: `buffer = malloc(sizeof(file_name));`  the parameter `file_name` is a pointer, so sizeof(file_name)  will return the size of a pointer, NOT the number of bytes in the char array `file_name`.

Comment: for good program practice and for readability and for ease of documentation,  only one variable declaration per statement and only one statement per line.

Comment: regarding this line: `argv[argc] = 0;`  argv[argc] should be a NULL pointer, not 0.  (although, in practice, they 'may' be the same thing)

Comment: in C, the argv array is NOT on the stack, rather only the actual char **argv pointer.  The actual char ** array and the individual char strings are in a read only memory page

Comment: actually, all of the character strings in argv[] array need to be aligned per the underlying architecture,  I.E. either 32 bit aligned or 64 bit aligned.